# Invoke a in-jar method at startup

Tags: jvm, java, invoke

I want to initialize my  external jar library when the JVM starts without a method call. Is there A way I can get a "On JVM Startup" method invoked in an external jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it without initializing the class where you have "On JVM Startup". Your best chance to do so is by creating "On JVM Startup" as a static method and calling it from the static block of the class. But static block will be called when the class is first referred, so you need to refer your class at the startup. Otherwise JVM can only load your class but cannot call any of its method without being referred.

But if you are working on a webapp then you can call an init method in a servlet when servlet is configured as load on startup.

Hope it helps!